# Border for whole html pages using css

Tags: html, css, border

I need to give border for all html  page using css including header and body of html 
in my web application.

Help is highly appreciation.

Comment: The question's grammar is not acceptable and it's not clear what you are asking. Also, Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- design the Style sheet.
- save it with .css extension
- user margin,border properties as you want with body tag.
  example.
   body 
  {
   margin-top:10px;
   margin-left:10px;
   border:1px solid #B6B6B6;
   moz-border-radius: 2px;
   khtml-border-radius: 2px;
   webkit-border-radius: 2px;
   border-radius: 2px;
  }
- link css to your html page. 
  example- link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" /
- save with html and execute.